# Log4j email error "Cannot find java.home ??"

Tags: email, log4j, jakarta-mail, java

I'm using log4j under J2SE. I've configured it to use a mailer for a certain type of log event.. When the logger.error triggers I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.Error: Can't find java.home ??
at sun.net.NetProperties.loadDefaultProperties(NetProperties.java:45)
...
at org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender.sendBuffer(SMTPAppender.java:416)
```

Anyone run into this before? I have the required mail.jar library included as well.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked at the source code of `NetProperties` and the error basically means what it says.  The System property called "java.home" is unset.  According to the javadoc for [`System.getProperties()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29), that property is set automatically by the JVM to the java installation directory.

The only explanation I can think of is that something in your application or some third-party library you are using has explicitly unset that property.   That is obviously a bad thing to do ...

Comment: Yup, I accidentally wiped System.properties, causing the problem.