# JAVA_HOME issue with logging class

Tags: java, logging, java-home

I get the following error even when my JAVA_HOME is set correctly.

C:\workspace-sts-2.8.0.RELEASE\JBClient\target>echo %JAVA_HOME%

C:\jdk1.6.0_31

I am not doing any logging I just have the following dependencies on my classpath (ALONGWITH THE JRE)

```
 - concurrent.jar 
 - hornetq-core-client-java5.jar
 - hornetq-jms-client-java5.jar 
 - jboss-aop-client.jar
 - jboss-aspect-jdk50-client.jar jboss-client.jar jboss-common-core.jar
 - jboss-ejb3-common-client.jar jboss-ejb3-core-client.jar
 - jboss-ejb3-proxy-impl-client.jar jboss-ejb3-proxy-spi-client.jar
 - jboss-ejb3-security-client.jar jboss-integration.jar jboss-javaee.jar
 - jboss-logging.jar jboss-remoting.jar jboss-security-spi.jar
 - jbossall-client.jar jbosssx-client.jar jnp-client.jar

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Can't find java.home ??
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.util.ClassLogger.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at main.java.JBClient.main(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.util.logging.LogManager
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$Cleaner.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359774/log4j-email-error-cannot-find-java-home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you cleaning / setting system properties somewhere earlier in your code? `java.util.logging.LogManager.readConfiguration` throws this error if it can't find `java.home` system property.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359774/log4j-email-error-cannot-find-java-home) - though not an exact duplicate (classes are different) it seems to be the same kind of problem.