# java.util.logging.LogManager.readConfiguration -- java.lang.Error: Can't find java.home?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, junit4, java-home

Getting following error while running UT cases in TestNG:

```
FAILED: TC1
java.lang.Error: Can't find java.home ??
at java.util.logging.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:1295)
at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:399)
at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:396)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:396)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$800(LogManager.java:145)
at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:345)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:338)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
```

> JAVA_HOME already set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45"

Did a lot of googling but found nothing, kindly help

Comment: Seems to be the same issue as mentioned here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347631/java-home-issue-with-logging-class...please check

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359774/log4j-email-error-cannot-find-java-home